# FAPI.UI.postMediatopic работает с type: "link", но не работает с type: "app"

Tags: mail.ru, odnoklassniki-api, одноклассники

У меня есть [словесная игра](https://ok.ru/game/slova.de), которая работает на Одноклассниках уже больше года, и также там без проблем работала продажа виртуальных товаров (я ее правда выключил в январе из-за утомительной отчетности).

Когда я вызываю следующий код - он работает и постит в https://ok.ru/feed

[image: ok]

```
FAPI.UI.postMediatopic({media: [
        {
                type: "link", 
                noImage: true, 
                imageUrl: "https://slova.de/words/board-492x364.php?gid=81236",
                url: "https://slova.de/game-81236",
        }
]});
```

А вот следующий код не работает -

[image: error]

```
FAPI.UI.postMediatopic({media: [
        {
                type: "app",
                text: "Игра 81236",
                images: [{
                        url: "https://slova.de/words/board-492x364.php?gid=81236",
                        title: "Игра 81236"
                }]
        }
]});
```

При этом callback-функция пишет в консоль error `topicFailed` или иногда пишет подробнее

> {"code":100,"message":"APP image has unsupported url https://slova.de/words/board-492x364.php?gid=81236"}

```
function API_callback(method, result, data) {
        if ("postMediatopic" == method) {
                console.log(result);
                console.log(data);
        }
}
```

В чем может быть причина?

Документацию к [mediatopic.post](https://apiok.ru/dev/methods/rest/mediatopic/mediatopic.post) и [FAPI.UI.postMediatopic](https://apiok.ru/dev/sdk/js/ui.postMediatopic/) я читал, чужой код на Github тоже...

Comment: С урлом оканчивающимся на `.jpg` пробовали? Возможно рачительные разработчики апи влепили какую-нибудь валидацию урла картинки приложения.

Comment: Не заметил сразу, что у вас png. Тогда попробуйте оканчивающийся на `.png`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что апи валидирует url картинки для типа `app` (то, что такой url работает для типа `link`, ничего не значит). Попробуйте использовать url оканчивающийся на `.png` (и без query-параметров). Например, `https://slova.de/words/board-492x364.png`. Сгенерируйте картинку заранее и сохраните по этому урлу или настройте веб-сервер, чтобы он передавал такой запрос на обработку вашем php-скрипту.

Comment: Спасибо, Егор! Статические jpg и png работают. Я тогда добавил "&fake=fake.png" к моему URL и это тоже работает.

Comment: "&fake=fake.png" -- клёвый хак :-)

Comment: Я поменял на "&fake=" + (+new Date()) + ".png" чтобы избежать кеширование