# mailru.common.stream.post возвращает publishFail

Tags: mail.ru

У меня есть [словесная игра](https://my.mail.ru/apps/743580), которая работает на Mail.ru (он же "Мой Мир") уже больше года, и также там без проблем работала продажа виртуальных товаров (я ее правда выключил в январе из-за утомительной отчетности).

Когда я вызываю следующий код, он почему-то возвращает `publishFail` в консоли:

[image: скриншот браузера]

```
var epoch = +new Date();
var desc = "Слова Фарбера, игра " + game.gid + ".\n" + 
        game.given1 + " - " + game.given2 + 
        ".\nСчёт " + game.score1 + ":" + game.score2;

mailru.events.listen(mailru.common.events.streamPublish, function(event) {
        // prints "publishFail" for some reason
        console.log(event.status);
});

mailru.common.stream.post({
        img_url: "https://slova.de/words/board3.php?gid=" + game.gid + "&fake=" + epoch + ".png",
        title: "Игра " + game.gid,
        text: desc,
        action_links: [{text: "Игра " + game.gid, href: "https://slova.de/game-" + game.gid}]
});
```

Я уже задавал [подобный вопрос, но для Одноклассников](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1014610/fapi-ui-postmediatopic-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-type-link-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81-type-app) - и там все разрешилось добавлением ".jpg" или ".png" к URL картинки, но здесь это не помогает.

Документацию к [mailru.common.stream.post](https://api.mail.ru/docs/reference/js/stream-post/) я читал, чужой код на GitHub тоже...

Причем интересно, что другой код (см. ниже), постящий ту же картинку, но в альбом пользователя, работает без проблем. Значит дело в какой-то недостающей мелочи?

```
mailru.common.photos.getAlbums(function(albums) {
        if (albums && albums.length > 0) {
                // try to find an album called _mypagephoto or take the 1st entry
                var i;
                var aid = albums[0].aid;
                for (i = 0; i < albums.length; i++) {
                       if ("_mypagephoto" == albums[i].aid) {
                               aid = "_mypagephoto";
                               break;
                       }
                }

                mailru.common.photos.upload({
                        url: "https://slova.de/words/board3.php?gid=" + game.gid + "&fake=" + epoch + ".png",
                        aid: aid,
                        name: "Игра " + game.gid,
                        description: desc
                });
        }
});
```

Comment: А где находится картинка которую вы не можете отправить?

Comment: Antonio, картинка: https://slova.de/words/board3.php?gid=81236 или https://slova.de/words/board3.php?gid=81236&fake=1234567890.png

Comment: В вашем вопросе вы приложили 2 картинки, одна с вашем кодом, другая с github. В этих кодах используются разные методы отправки mailru.common.photos.upload , а в вашем mailru.common.stream.post. Возможно это влияет ??

Comment: В моем вопросе нет картинок с GitHub. Там только картинки с игрового сервера slova.de (см. мой комментарий выше)